# Adding Config/RouteProvider breaks ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This issue is most likely due to my naivity as I am just beginning to teach myself JS and AngularJS in parallel. I have put together a simple example of what I am seeing in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WmTERAX8UdusPMmBwnzt?p=preview). Basically, my app handles an ng-repeat correctly, but as soon as I add the config method it does not replace {{menuItem.itemName}} with the value of the variable. Now, my config method is currently empty, so that may be the problem. But, I assumed I could just have a no-op method and add routes as I went, testing each one.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html ng-app="site">
    <head>
        <script src = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js></script>
        <script src ="script.js"></script>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <title>Site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
    <body ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
      <div id="main-container">
        <div id="header">Site
        </div>
        <div id="side-bar">
          <ul id="side-bar-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems"><span class="underline"><a ng-href={{menuItem.itemLink}}>{{menuItem.itemName}}</a></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('site',[]).
       controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.menuItems = [{
                itemName: "Home",
                itemLink: "#Home"
        }];
}]);

//enabling the config breaks the output (and of course ; 
//above needs to be replaced with . when config enabled)
/*config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {}]);*/
```

Comment: you are missing `ngRoute` in the module dependencies

Comment: On additional clarification: I had to add the script source angular-route.js to my html as well.